# UISearchBar in UINavigationControllers NavigationBar (like google currents for iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c

In the current Google Currents iOS App (March 30th, 2013) there is a search button in the upper right corner. If you tap it, the button moves to the left and a text field 'grows' out of the right side. The other buttons are moved out of the left side in the same animation.

My question is: how would you achieve a behaviour like this? Is it possible to achieve this with UINavigationController (and UISearchBar/UISearchDisplayController) and other default iOS controls or did google wrote their own navigation controller? I appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is use a UIView animation and widen the frame of the search bar.
You will have to reduce it also in the same fashion...

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 
                  delay:0.0
                options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
             animations:^{
                 searchFrame.size.width += 300;
                 searchbar.frame = searchFrame;
             }
             completion:nil];
```

Comment: But how would your view hierarchy look like? Would you simply put a UISearchBar in a custom UIBarButtonItem?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  It's up to you how to implement it, but that would be a standard way of doing it.